# Was a self-driving car pulled over by police for the first time last month (November 2015)?

Tags: road-vehicles, law-enforcement, police

I read in this [Bloomberg article](http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2015-12-18/humans-are-slamming-into-driverless-cars-and-exposing-a-key-flaw)

> Google cars have been in 17 minor crashes in 2 million miles (3.2 million kilometers) of testing.
>
> [...]
>
> Ten days later, a Mountain View motorcycle cop noticed traffic stacking up behind a Google car going 24 miles an hour in a busy 35 mph zone. He zoomed over and became the first officer to stop a robot car.

I'm surprised that no other self-driving car got pulled over before, given that Google cars drove 3.2 million kilometers (and there are other car manufacturers).

Comment: That's the first one I've heard of pulled over. They have been involved in accidents, though. If you think about it, with the Google cars so strictly following traffic rules, there's no real reason for the police to pull them over. In this case, the car was even drving legally for the area as there was no minimum speed limit listed.

Comment: **Self-driving cars are far better at driving than human beings are. Self-driving cars never get distracted, never blink, never doze off, never talk on cell phones, never get drunk, etc. In addition, the self-driving car has a 360-degree view and multiple sensors that humans will never have.** [Read more](http://marshallbrain.com/second-intelligent-species4.htm)

Comment: Sort of short-circuits the standard opening:  "Do you know how fast you were going?" produces a 100K log file dump...

Comment: @SeanDuggan While they strictly follow driving rules as they perceive them you could still commit a traffic offense by failing to correctly assess the situation.

Comment: What sort of information would convince you that the article is true? Googe's statement? (could be lying). Citation records for entire USA to be grepped? Sworn statement from someone at google in front of court?